# Spring inject different implementations of one interface inside each other

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Say I have an interface called **Worker** and I have 3 implementations of Worker interface:

**Accountant, Developer, Manager**.

```
public interface Worker {

}

@Service
public class Accountant implements Worker {

}

@Service
public class Developer implements Worker {

}

@Service
public class Manager implements Worker {

}
```

Question: Is it okay if I inject one implementation into another or it counts as a bad practice?

Say I want to inject **Developer** into **Accountant** and **Manager** into **Developer**

Comment: This is depends on my business requirements, for example creating Accountant entity I need  to create Developers and Managers related to Accountant with the special status

Comment: I was thinking of getting rid of interface and creating something like management service which will inject all three separate services and do it's work. Maybe this solution would be better, what do you think ?